# Epoxy Carousel nesting vertical scroll with Tabs

Tags: android, epoxy

I'm looking to achieve this with [Epoxy](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy). The reason for this is I have build a single tab but want to create two tabs with the Tab row. It's recommended to use the [Carousel](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy/wiki/Carousel) with Epoxy as the ViewPager replacement but I don't see how to do these two things with Epoxy:

- Create the tabs with indicator that responds to page swiping
- Nest the vertical row models in each Carousel model. The Carousel takes a single model, but what I need here is several models together.

Are there any example projects where the below is done with Epoxy?

Currently, I've achieved this by wrapping a ViewPager2 in a CoordinatorLayout with the Header. The ViewPager2 has Fragments that hold an EpoxyRecyclerView. It would be nice to have the entire screen Epoxy though.

[image]